# Launch App after Background downloading in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, download, ios7, xcode5

Is there any feature in iOS7 to `launch app` after complete downloading in the background in iOS7.
As the method which get called in background after complete download is

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

I want to launch app in foreground once this method called or download completes.

is there any method available something like this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:]];
```

anything else in place of `openURL` to launching the app in the foreground

or

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState=UIApplicationStateActive
```

Answer (score 2):

From the ["What's New in iOS7" docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html) under the "Multitasking Enhancements" section:

> Apps that regularly update their content by contacting a server can register with the system and be launched periodically to retrieve that content in the background. To register, include the UIBackgroundModes key with the fetch value in your app’s Info.plist file. Then, when your app is launched, call the setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval: method to determine how often it receives update messages. Finally, you must also implement the application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: method in your app delegate.

and one paragraph later we have:

> Apps supporting either the fetch or remote-notification background modes may be launched or moved from the suspended to background state at appropriate times. **In the case of the fetch background mode**, the **system uses available information to determine the best time to launch or wake apps. For example, it does so when networking conditions are good or when the device is already awake.** You can also send silent push notifications—that is, notifications that do not display alerts or otherwise disturb the user.

and finally we have [the link included in the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4)

Comment: I am done with the all the steps (info.plist ) and setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method but `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler` method is not getting called in from background as well as foreground